# Flutter Custom Marker / InfoWindow

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, google-maps-markers

I'm using flutter with google_maps_flutter package (^0.5.20+3), with this version you can't keep opened by default the infowindow or add svg icons easily.

I thought of a way to do it and it was to load a widget as I want the marker to come out, take a screenshoot and that image pass it to the marker so that it appears on the map.

I managed to get it on the map, but when im in the loop of my endpoint for add the markers, they did not finish adding the marker with the icon on the map when it tried to add the next one. This generates that at the last point you add the marker icon of the previous one.

Hope you can give me some ligth in here. Thanks

```
  import 'dart:async';

  import 'dart:typed_data';
  import 'dart:ui' as ui;
  import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
  import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

  import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

  class ShowMapPage extends StatefulWidget {
    ShowMapPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
    final String title;
    @override
    ShowMapPageState createState() => ShowMapPageState();
  }

  class ShowMapPageState extends State<ShowMapPage> {
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
              loadMap(), //Loads the google map             
              //here i put here content 
              RepaintBoundary(
                key: _globalKey,
                child: displaySVG() //add one icon without text/rotation
              ),
            ])),
      );

      @override
      void initState() {
        callRestAPI();
        super.initState();
      }

      callRestAPI() async {
        var rec = await callTheServiceAPI();
        setState(() {
          _recorrido = rec;        
        });
        addMarkers();
      }

      displaySVG() {
        return MarkerIcon(
          nombreIcono: nombreIcono,
          rotacionIcono: rotacionIcono
        );
      }

      //Here's how i make the loop for add the markers to the map
      addMarkers() async {
        for (var i = 0; i < _recorrido.length; i++) {

          final m = _recorrido[i];
          var velocidad = m['properties']['velocidad'];
          var nombreMovil = m['properties']['nombre_movil'];
          var position = LatLng(m['geometry']['coordinates'][1], m['geometry']['coordinates'][0]);
          var rotacion = m['properties']['orientacion'];

          setState(() {
            nombreIcono = nombreMovil;
            rotacionIcono = rotacion;     
          });     

          BitmapDescriptor icon = await _capturePng(); //flechaIcon;      

          var markerId = i;
          final Marker marker = Marker(
              markerId: MarkerId(markerId.toString()),
              position: position,
              infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                title: nombreMovil,
              ),
              icon: await icon,
              onTap: () {

              }
          );
          if (this.mounted){
            setState(() {
              // adding a new marker to marker list
              print('Marker loaded');
              _markers.add(marker);
            });
          }
        }
      }

      _capturePng() async {
        try {
          print('_capturePng - Start '+DateTime.now().toString());
          inside = true;      
          RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = _globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
          ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
          ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
          Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    //    String bs64 = base64Encode(pngBytes);
          setState(() {
            //imageInMemory = pngBytes;
            inside = false;
          });
          print('_capturePng - End '+DateTime.now().toString());      
          return BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(pngBytes);
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }        
      }

    }
  }


  class MarkerIcon extends StatefulWidget {
    Function callback;
    MarkerIcon({Key key, this.callback, this.nombreIcono, this.rotacionIcono}) : super(key: key);
    String nombreIcono;
    int rotacionIcono;
    _MarkerIconState createState() => _MarkerIconState();
  }

  class _MarkerIconState extends State<MarkerIcon> {

    String iconMarker = './assets/ico_car.svg';

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Stack(
        overflow: Overflow.visible,
        fit: StackFit.loose,    
        children: <Widget>[
            label(),
            iconMarker()
        ]
      );
    }    
    label() {
      return Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))
        ),
        child: Text(
            widget.nombreIcono,
            style: TextStyle( 
            color: Colors.white, 
            fontSize: 12, 
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700
          )
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0)
      );
    }

    svgIcon() {
      return SvgPicture.asset(
          iconMarker,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: Colors.red,
          height: 50.0,
          width: 50.0,
          allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
      );
    }

    iconMarker() {
      return Container(
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,    
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:35, left:0),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          child: RotationTransition(
            turns: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation(widget.rotacionIcono / 360),
            child: svgIcon(),
          )
      );
    }

  }
```

Comment: Do you still encounter this issue with the latest version of `google_maps_flutter ` plugin? If yes, could you provide a working minimal repro http://stackoverflow.com/mcve that can be run locally? Adding screenshots for the expected and actual behavior will also help people better understand the issue.